# c++ .No member function declared in the class

Tags: c++

I am trying to write some algorithm. I have divided the code into three files:
euler_tour.cpp, euler_tour.h, use.cpp. The code is as follows:

```
//euler_tour.h
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#ifndef euler
#define euler
class euler_t{
std::vector<int> eul,first, height;
std::vector<bool> vis;
std::map<int,std::vector<int>> mp;
public:
euler_t(int n);
void print();
void add_edge(int,int);
void dfs(int u,int h);
};
#endif
```

```
//euler_tour.cpp
#include "euler_tour.h"
euler_t::euler_t(int n):eul(n,0),height(n,0),first(n+1,0),vis(n,false),mp{}{
std::cout<<"initialized"<<std::endl;
}
void euler_t::print(){
 //some implementation
}
void euler_t::add_edge(int u,int v){
   //some implementation.
}

void euler_t::dfs(int u,int h){
  //some implementation.
}
```

When I am trying to compile euler_tour.cpp, I throws these errors:

```
euler_tour.cpp:2:1: error: redefinition of ‘euler_t::euler_t(int)’
 euler_t::euler_t(int n):eul(n,0),height(n,0),first(n+1,0),vis(n,false),mp{}{
 ^~~~~~~
euler_tour.h:7:1: note: ‘euler_t::euler_t(int)’ previously defined here
 std::map<int,std::vector<int>> mp;
 ^~~~~~~
euler_tour.cpp:2:76: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
 euler_t::euler_t(int n):eul(n,0),height(n,0),first(n+1,0),vis(n,false),mp{}{
                                                                            ^
euler_tour.cpp:17:35: error: no ‘void euler_t::add_edge(int, int)’ member function declared in class ‘euler_t’
 void euler_t::add_edge(int u,int v){
```

But if I copy the code in euler_tour.cpp into euler_tour.h, then it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Use.cpp includes euler_tour.h and makes an object of this class and calls the functions.

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Did you copy/paste the exact code that's giving you an error?

Comment: Yes, I tried it once again, it still gives the error.

Comment: Maybe old gcc? what is the compiler version?

Comment: gcc version 7.5.0

Comment: Try minimizing your example further.  The fact it's complaining about a member variable being declared strikes me as odd.

Comment: I randomly made a mistake and tried to compile it, and when I revert the changes, it starts running. I swear I didn't make any additional changes. What could be the reason, for this to happen?. Anyways thank you.

Comment: also don't include  [bits/stdc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)